# Unicode ImportError using graphlab with Enthought iPython

Tags: python, unicode, enthought, graphlab

I am trying to use GraphLab Create with Enthought Canopy iPython but I'm getting an ImportError that seems to be related to unicode.  The line is: 
    `ImportError: /home/aaron/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/cython/cy_ipc.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeUTF8`

and this is preceded by:

```
In [1]: import graphlab
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4b66ad388e97> in <module>()
----> 1 import graphlab

/home/aaron/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/__init__.py in <module>()
  5 """
  6
----> 7 import graphlab.connect.aws as aws
  8
  9 import graphlab.deploy

/home/aaron/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/connect/aws/__init__.py in <module>()
  3 This module defines classes and global functions for interacting with Amazon Web Services.
  4 """
----> 5 from _ec2 import get_credentials, launch_EC2, list_instances, set_credentials, status, terminate_EC2

/home/aaron/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/connect/aws/_ec2.py in <module>()
 15
 16 import graphlab.product_key
---> 17 import graphlab.connect.server as glserver
 18 import graphlab.connect.main as glconnect
 19 from graphlab.connect.main import __catch_and_log__

/home/aaron/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/connect/server.py in <module>()
  4 """
  5
----> 6 from graphlab.cython.cy_ipc import PyCommClient as Client
  7 from graphlab.cython.cy_ipc import get_public_secret_key_pair
  8 from graphlab_util.config import DEFAULT_CONFIG as default_local_conf
In [1]: import graphlab
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4b66ad388e97> in <module>()
----> 1 import graphlab

/home/aaron/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/__init__.py in <module>()
  5 """
  6
----> 7 import graphlab.connect.aws as aws
  8
  9 import graphlab.deploy

/home/aaron/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/connect/aws/__init__.py in <module>()
  3 This module defines classes and global functions for interacting with Amazon Web Services.
  4 """
----> 5 from _ec2 import get_credentials, launch_EC2, list_instances, set_credentials, status, terminate_EC2

/home/aaron/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/connect/aws/_ec2.py in <module>()
 15
 16 import graphlab.product_key
---> 17 import graphlab.connect.server as glserver
 18 import graphlab.connect.main as glconnect
 19 from graphlab.connect.main import __catch_and_log__

/home/aaron/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/connect/server.py in <module>()
  4 """
  5
----> 6 from graphlab.cython.cy_ipc import PyCommClient as Client
  7 from graphlab.cython.cy_ipc import get_public_secret_key_pair
  8 from graphlab_util.config import DEFAULT_CONFIG as default_local_conf
```

The GraphLab forum http://forum.graphlab.com/discussion/84/importerror-undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs4-decodeutf8 suggests that this is due to Enthought Python being compiled with 2-byte-wide unicode chars.  Is there a way to get Enthought to use 4-byte chars since I can't recompile?